# How to Download all mail with attachments to server using PHP IMAP?

Tags: php, gmail, imap, yahoo, hotmail

Using PHP IMAP function i can read email, but i need to run autoamtically or manually to download messages , how can i download all email messages with or without attachments and saved it to local drive or server in mailid folder name for major networks (gmail,yahoo,hotmail,AOL).

Comment: read this: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-imap-download-email/

Comment: @shivan  -- thanks , but its basic to just view messages , i need to run loop through and download all mails in my local server

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please try this code to fetch the email and store attachments in a directory.

You can also delete the mail using imap_delete and imap_expunge, after you have fetched it from the mailbox.

In the below code set your website name, mailbox username, password and path for storing attachments.

```
if( $mbox = imap_open("{yoursitename.com:110/pop3/notls}INBOX", "username of mailbox", "password of mailbox")){
    $path = "set path here for where the attachments are store";
    $check = imap_mailboxmsginfo($mbox);     
    function getmsg($mbox,$mid) {   
        global $charset,$htmlmsg,$plainmsg,$attachments,$from,$to,$subj,$timages,$path;
        $htmlmsg = $plainmsg = $charset = '';
        $attachments = array();
        // HEADER
        $h = imap_headerinfo($mbox,$mid);
        // add code here to get date, from, to, cc, subject...
        $date = $h->date;
        $from = $h->fromaddress;
        $to = $h->toaddress;
          $subj = htmlspecialchars($h->Subject);
        // BODY
        $s = imap_fetchstructure($mbox,$mid);
        if (!$s->parts)  // simple
        getpart($mbox,$mid,$s,0);  // pass 0 as part-number
        else {  // multipart: cycle through each part
        foreach ($s->parts as $partno0=>$p)
          getpart($mbox,$mid,$p,$partno0+1);
        }
    }

    function getpart($mbox,$mid,$p,$partno) {
        // $partno = '1', '2', '2.1', '2.1.3', etc for multipart, 0 if simple
        global $htmlmsg,$plainmsg,$charset,$attachments,$partid,$last_mail_id,$patterns,$pic,$newstr,$c,$ok,$timages,$subj,$path;
        $patterns = array();
        $pic =  array();
        $image=array();
        $data = ($partno) ? imap_fetchbody($mbox,$mid,$partno) : imap_body($mbox,$mid);  // simple
        if ($p->encoding==4)
        $data = quoted_printable_decode($data);
        else if ($p->encoding==3)
        $data = base64_decode($data);
        // PARAMETERS    // get all parameters, like charset, filenames of attachments, etc.
        $params = array();
        if ($p->parameters)
        foreach ($p->parameters as $x)
            $params[strtolower($x->attribute)] = $x->value;
        if ($p->dparameters)
        foreach ($p->dparameters as $x)
            $params[strtolower($x->attribute)] = $x->value;

        // ATTACHMENT    // Any part with a filename is an attachment,
        // so an attached text file (type 0) is not mistaken as the message.
        if ($params['filename'] || $params['name']) {
        $partid = htmlentities($p->id,ENT_QUOTES);

           // filename may be given as 'Filename' or 'Name' or both
        $filename = ($params['filename'])? $params['filename'] : $params['name'];
        // filename may be encoded, so see imap_mime_header_decode()
         $attachments[$filename] = $data;  // this is a problem if two files have same name
        //store id and filename in array
        $image[$key] = $filename;

        }
        //save the attachments in the directory
        foreach( $attachments as $key => $val){
          $fname = $key;
          $fp = fopen("$path/$fname","w");
          fwrite($fp, $val);
          fclose($fp);
        }
            // TEXT
            if ($p->type==0 && $data) {
            // Messages may be split in different parts because of inline attachments,   // so append parts together with blank row.
            if (strtolower($p->subtype)=='plain')
                $plainmsg .= trim($data)."\n\n";
            else
                //preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i',$data, $result);
                $htmlmsg .= $data."<br><br>";
                $charset = $params['charset'];  // assume all parts are same charset
            }

        // There are no PHP functions to parse embedded messages, so this just appends the raw source to the main message.
        else if ($p->type==2 && $data) {
        $plainmsg .= $data."\n\n";
        }
        // SUBPART RECURSION
        if ($p->parts) {
        foreach ($p->parts as $partno0=>$p2)
            getpart($mbox,$mid,$p2,$partno.'.'.($partno0+1));  // 1.2, 1.2.1, etc.
        }
    }

    $attachments = array();
    $num_msg = imap_num_msg($mbox);
    if($num_msg>0) {
        getmsg($mbox,1);
    }else {
         echo "Sorry!...No Messages in MailBox...<br>";
    }

    //imap_delete and imap_expunge are used to delete the mail after fetching....Uncomment it if you want to delete the mail from mailbox
    //imap_delete($mbox,1); 
    //imap_expunge($mbox);
    imap_close($mbox);

}else { exit ("Can't connect: " . imap_last_error() ."\n");  echo "FAIL!\n";  };
```

Comment: Code is very useful, but needs updating for newer versions of PHP please.